# How would I export my results to a .txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, export

I have the following code running and I would like to have the output of the script exported to a .txt file for later viewing. How could I go about doing this?

```
import socket, threading


def TCP_connect(ip, port_number, delay, output):
    TCPsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    TCPsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    TCPsock.settimeout(delay)
try:
    TCPsock.connect((ip, port_number))
    output[port_number] = 'Listening'
except:
    output[port_number] = ''



def scan_ports(host_ip, delay):

    threads = []        # To run TCP_connect concurrently
    output = {}         # For printing purposes

# Spawning threads to scan ports
for i in range(10000):
    t = threading.Thread(target=TCP_connect, args=(host_ip, i, delay, output))
    threads.append(t)

# Starting threads
for i in range(10000):
    threads[i].start()

# Locking the script until all threads complete
for i in range(10000):
    threads[i].join()

# Printing listening ports from small to large
for i in range(10000):
    if output[i] == 'Listening':
        print(str(i) + ': ' + output[i])



def main():
host_ip = input("Enter host IP: ")
delay = int(input("How many seconds the socket is going to wait until timeout: "))
scan_ports(host_ip, delay)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

print ("Thank you for scanning")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files. If you're using bash, you could just do something like `python file.py > file.txt`

Comment: I suggest you look at the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module. You can configure it to output to both the console and a file.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("your_desired_txt_filename", "a") as myFile:
```

Then, at the part where you want to write to the file:

```
myFile.write(your_content) ## Indent this line with the suitable level of indentation (it will be at least one indentation level  deeper than the `with` clause
```

Comment: You cannot append to a file object. You mean `myFile.write(your_content)`. Also it would need to be indented under the `with`

Comment: @MartinEvans Just realised what you mean ... fixed it :)